# Travel to US on one-way ticket using R B1 OCS Visa

Tags: visas, uk-citizens

I am travelling for work in the Gulf of Mexico on a R B1 OCS Visa. I wish to book a one-way ticket for now, and book my return closer to the date. Am I allowed to do this?

Comment: Normally travellers on B1 can fly with a one-way ticket, however, I am not sure whether this also applies to B1 OCS. All I can find online is that you can only use it for travel to and from your off shore site.

Comment: @Midavalo the only explicit requirement for a round-trip ticket applies to travelers using the visa waiver program, so not in this case.